# How to change a react state immediately by setTimeout after setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

new in react here, don't know if it's right to do this on the setState callback like this?

```
           setTimeout(()=> {
            this.setState((state, props) => ({ activateLightColorForRed: true }), () => {
              setTimeout(()=> {
                this.setState(()=> ({ activateLightColorForRed: false }))
              }, 500);
              red.play();
            })
          }, toWait);
```

or maybe something like this?

```
 this.setState((state, props) => {
    this.setState((state, props) => {
      activateLightColorForRed: true
    });
    setTimeout(() => { activateLightColorForRed: false },500)
  })
```

are the state on the setState callback updated? something weird is happening in my components, it's rendering multiple times. I am not sure but I think it's because I'm doing the first sample?

Comment: could you post the full code for the component? Are you calling setState from within the render method?

Comment: Heads-up @i-am-newbie : `setState` are asynchronous in nature and you could also use simply `this.setState({activateLightColorForRed:true})` i.e. pass a object instead of passing in a function. Might help in readability. And yeah post the complete code for the component. It will help us. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question does not seem to follow the pattern of a regular react app. You should be using the lifecycle events to *react* to the state being changed. You should not be making multiple, nested, confusing callbacks (like it seems you want to do).

Might I suggest a structure more like this

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activateLightColorForRed: false,
    };
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.activateLightColorForRed) {
      // when the state is updated (turned red), 
      // a timeout is triggered to switch it back off
      this.turnOffRedTimeout = setTimeout(() => { 
        this.setState(() => ({activateLightColorForRed: false}))
      }, 500);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // we set the timeout to this.turnOffRedTimeout so that we can
    // clean it up when the component is unmounted.
    // otherwise you could get your app trying to modify the state on an
    // unmounted component, which will throw an error
    clearTimeout(this.turnOffRedTimeout);
  }
  render () {
    // really simply ui to show how it *could* work
    return (
      <div onClick={this.turnLightRed}>
        The light is {this.state.activateLightColorForRed ? "Red" : "Green"}.
        <br /> Click to change!
      </div>
    )
  }
  turnLightRed = () => {
    // this function will turn the light red
    this.setState(() => ({ 
      activateLightColorForRed: true 
    }));
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: being new in react this is very helpful. most of the time i have to re read docs.

Comment: From React docs: "This method is not called for the initial render." This won't work.

Comment: What are you talking about @YasinYaqoobi? Please be more specific to what you think won't work

Comment: componentDidUpdate is not called on initial render https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating-componentdidupdate, so the timeout never gets called. Even after clicking when the state is red, it doesn't automatically change to "green"

Comment: `componentDidUpdate` is not supposed to fire onLoad. It fires after the state is updated; when the button is clicked. Then the timeout starts and reverts the state after 500ms. 
I am quite confident that this works.

Comment: I updated the code above, and I discovered a spelling error in the code as well; but I am still using componentDidUpdate and it works.